# Compiling an element with AngularJs attributes after the page is loaded

Tags: angularjs

I need to create multiple `<a ng-click="controller.doThat(X)">` elemets, based on a response from some `$http` call. And add them to an element designated by its id attribute.

I am using AngularJs v1.6.4. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newElem = $compile(t)($scope);
document.getElementById("designatedDiv").appendChild(newElem[0]);
```

does the job as long as `t` is a string of a single element:

```
var t = "try and press <a ng-click=\"controller.doThat(X)\">here</a> and see..."
```

will result in:

```
Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/jqLite/nosel
    at angular.min.js:6
```

BUT if you redo the last example as following:

```
var t = "<span>try and press </span><a ng-click=\"controller.doThat(X)\">here</a><span> and see...</span>"
var newElem = $compile(t)($scope);
for (i=0;i<newElem.length;i++)
    document.getElementById("designatedDiv").appendChild(newElem[i]);
```

then it works as expected.